# How to properly release object?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I know that in iOS 5 there is automatic reference counting which takes away the need for all of this but it is very simple anyway.

Is it good practice to set an object to nil before you release it or is it vice versa where you release it then set it to nil?

Anyway, I just want to get rid of **any** possibilities of crashes in my app and I just want this way to prevent it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `release` on nil accomplishes nothing.

Comment: But it would prevent a crash and the object would still get released wouldn't it?

Comment: The standard way was (pre ARC): `[ someObject release ]; someObject = nil;`

Comment: That doesn't preclude crashes, but it does make it easier to see when you might not have released something.

Comment: The pointer would not be around any more to dereference, if that is what you mean by preventing crashes.

Answer (score 1):

When you use automatic reference counting, you cannot call `release`. It is a compiler error to do so.

In manual reference counting, you should `release` and then set to `nil`. Setting a variable to `nil` and then calling `release` leaks the object (it does not release it). It won't crash, but it will eat memory (eventually possibly so much memory that the OS will shut you down).

ARC is your absolute best tool for helping reduce crashes. There is no mechanism that can remove all possibilities of crashes. But two very simple rules will help:

- Use ARC if at all possible.
- Turn on "Treat Warnings as Errors." Never allow warnings in Objective-C.

There are many other smaller rules, but those are the two that every iOS developer should start with.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't set it to nil before you release the object, if you set it to nil, basically you lose pointer to your object, and now your variable is pointing to nil. Sending release to nil does nothing. If you want to protect yourself from garbage value / pointer, you can set it to nil, after you release the object. But, I don't see why you need to set it to nil other than if it's an instance variable.